# AspNetUser 1:n Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make  a 1:n relationship between AspNetUser and Movie, so one user can own many Movies.

Therefore I added the Following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies{ get; set; } 
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
}
```

But now i have the Problem that i can`t reference to AspNetUser because there is no AspNetUserModel.

```
public partial class Movie
{
    public long MovieId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

So when I now create the Database  the Movie table has a Primary key id , an attribute Name and a Foreign Key ApplicationUser_Id with relationship to AspNetUser Id.

So basically I got what I wanted, but how can I now access this property because in my Model I miss it.

Comment: I don't fully get the question; do you actually want to access the ApplicationUser_Id on your Movie entity?

Comment: I want to be able for Example to Scaffold the Film controller and be able to see in the view to which User the which Film belongs. Or when create a new Film to be able to select the Owner via a dropdown menu.

Comment: In ApplicationDbContext you have 'public DbSet<Film> Movie'. is Film an other entity or you meant to write Movie there?

Comment: sry i change the names for better understanding and missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class Movie
{
     public long MovieId { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string UserId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("UserId")]
     public virtual ApplicationUser Owner {set;get;}
}
```

Actually the point is that you can't set a navigation property to "required" as it's something that EF resolves for you, and not really a field in the DB. That's why you need to set the FK property to required and to wire it up with the navigation property (`[ForeignKey()]` attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your solution a little bit and now it works...

```
public partial class Movie
{
public long MovieId { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string name { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Owner")]
public string OwnerID { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser Owner {set;get;}
}
```

Unfortunatly when i scaffold the model it creates some

```
ViewBag.OwnerID = new SelectList(db.ApplicationUsers, "Id", "Email", film.OwnerID);
```

But the ApplicationDbContext does not contain db.ApplicationUsers so it throws an error. So manualy changed it to.

```
ViewBag.OwnerID = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Email");
```

and now it works....